# Range with alphabets Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list like this `string = ['A1', 'A5']`, I want to create a new list which should start from `A1` and end at `A5`.

**E.g** `['A1','A5'] -> ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']`

Similarly for this case `['A1', 'C1'] -> ['A1','B1','C1']`.

My approach was to create a LinkedList node for A1 and then increment the integer constant with every new creation of node and then append them together.

How can this be done?

Comment: What is the sequence between e.g. `'A1'` and `'C3'`? `A1,A2,A3,B3,C3`, `A1,B1,C1,C2,C3`, `A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3`? If you know the pattern than you can just use e.g. `map('A{}'.format, range(1, 3+1))`.

Comment: The sequence are only row-wise or column-wise as in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cloud **us an simple generator** called `customRange()`:

```
def customRange(lst):
    if lst[0][0] != lst[1][0]:
        for c in range(ord(lst[0][0]), ord(lst[1][0])+1):
            yield chr(c) + lst[0][1]
    else:
        for n in range(int(lst[0][1]), int(lst[1][1])):
            yield lst[0][0] + str(n)
```

---

Usage:

```
for value in customRange(['A1', 'A5']):
    print(value)

A1
A2
A3
A4
```

or

```
for value in customRange(['A1', 'D1']):
    print(value)

A1
B1
C1
D1
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer for the first case

This works well for your given pattern but not for changes like "a" instead of "A" I leave that to you

```
string = ['A1', 'A5']
if string[0][0]==string[1][0]:
    string=[string[0][0]+str(d) for d in range(int(string[0][1]),int(string[len(string)-1][1]))]
else:
    string=[chr(d)+string[0][1] for d in range(ord(string[0][0]),ord(string[len(string)-1][0])+1)]
```

In the else part you can try the second case :

Answer (score 1):

Extract the characters and digits from the substrings:

```
ch = "".join(c for c in l[0] if c.isalpha())

start, end = int("".join(c for c in l[0] if c.isdigit())), int("".join(c for c in l[-1] if c.isdigit()))
print(["{}{}".format(ch,i) for i in range(int(start),int(end)+1)])
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
```

If the range always starts at 1 you don't need to extract the start.

Comment: Please put `start =` and `end = ` in two lines. The scollbar hurts the readability